# Button touchupinside action done automatically on view appear?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I want Button action done automatically when a view load. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are correct in that setting the action that your button is tied to, then in your `viewDidLoad:`, call that function will work. I will just chime in with another method for others info.

You can send it a control event telling it that the button should act as if it has been pressed:

```
[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This is useful when you do not have an outlet to the button. For instance, I created an app where the user can press on a web view and launch a youtube video. It was also required that if the user presses a "video" button, then the same youtube video would launch. Basically, I had to fire a press event on the web view. So i searched through its views and found the button, from there I called the above line, and the webview pushes a video view controller for the youtube video.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly Yes. Call your method as

assuming your method declaration as

```
-(IBAction)yourButtonTapEvent:(id)sender;

[self yourButtonTapEvent:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your `viewDidAppear` method, just call the action you are providing for that specific button.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
    [self yourButtonAction:nil];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```